# Property 'maxCount' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am trying to implement antd upload button functionality in tsx file but for some reason I am getting the **following Typescript error**.

I have also created an interface for the same but no luck. Please suggest me where I am doing it wrong. Thanks

[image]

```
Type '{ children: Element; maxCount: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & UploadProps<any> & { children?: ReactNode; } & RefAttributes<any>'.
  Property 'maxCount' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & UploadProps<any> & { children?: ReactNode; } & RefAttributes<any>'
```

**Here is the code**

```
interface IMyProps {
    maxCount: number,
    }
    
const AdminPage: React.FC<IMyProps> = ({maxCount}) => {
      const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
    
        const onFinish = (values:any) => {
          console.log(values)
         };
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <div>
                <Modal title="Create" visible={isModalVisible} footer={null} onCancel={()=>setIsModalVisible(false)}>
                    <Form layout="vertical" onFinish={onFinish}>
                        <Form.Item label="Upload" name="uploading" >
                            <Upload  maxCount={1}> <---------------- GETTING ERROR HERE
                                <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to Upload</Button>
                            </Upload>
                        </Form.Item>
                        <Form.Item>
                            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                                Submit
                            </Button>
                            </Form.Item>
                    </Form>
                </Modal>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
          )
    }
    
    export default AdminPage;
```

Comment: How are the types of `Upload` defined?

Comment: I did not understand.... There were no errors related to upload type

Comment: Are you sure? For me it looks like the error comes from the `<Upload />` component.

Comment: @Gh05d , it is showing `Warning: [antd: Upload] `value` is not a valid prop, do you mean `fileList`?`

Comment: The error message says your `Upload` component don't have this prop `maxCount`

Comment: @Sohaib but antd documentation says its there.... "Upload - Ant Design" https://ant.design/components/upload/

Comment: You maybe missing types or using older version of antd

Comment: The same modal code worked fine in jsx format